# How can we pass a color as a prop?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component which has the color white if it is active and black if it is inactive. How can a pass the color black as a prop?

My code right now (it does nothing):

```
export function Card (props) {
  return <div {...props} className={styles.gray} />
}
```

I want to use this component (called `Card`) in a ternary operator to show if the component is active or not.

Comment: Can you, please, add more code?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are setting the active state outside of the card, here's the simple ternary pattern.

If active is defined outside of the card:

```js
function Card({ isActive, ...props }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`${styles.gray} ${isActive ? styles.active : null}`}
      {...props}
    />
  )
}
```

Using a helper like `clsx`, it would look like:

```
<div className={
  clsx(
    styles.gray,
    isActive ? styles.active : null,
  )
} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `styles` the name of your css style sheet and `gray` the selector?

There are a bunch of different ways to create this behavior, but an easy one if you have a props object with `color` as a prop, you can do:
`<div style={{ color: props.color }}`